# Probability of dice roll based on user input

Tags: python, statistics, probability

I have to write a programme that will take the users input of what number they would like to roll and return the probability of it. I have managed to get a code working that will give me the probability of it using two dices rolled 100 times however I cannot work out how to get this to work based on the user input.

This is what I have so far:

```
from random import randint

number = int(input ("You have two dice to roll, what outcome do you want? "))
outcome = {2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0}
sim = 100

for simulations in range(sim):
    first_dice_roll = randint(1, 6)
    second_dice_roll = randint(1, 6)
    sum_dice = first_dice_roll + second_dice_roll
    outcome[sum_dice] += 1
for key in outcome.keys():
    if outcome == 1:
        print("Percentage for rolling a sum of %s is: %s" % (key, outcome[key] / sim * 100))
```

Can anyone offer some assistance please?

Comment: Were you told to simulate it or acually calculate the probability? 
Beacus there is an easy way to calculate the probability without simlulating. 
Just devide the number of outcomes that can make your desired value by the total number of possibel outcomes. using 7 as an example, there are 6 outcomes of two dice that can make this value, the total combinations for 2 dice are 36. 6/36=0,1666666 and just multiply by 100 to get the percent 16,6%

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are pretty close to the correct solution, but you have a slight issue in your conditional check where you're comparing outcome to 1, rather than checking if the key is equal to the user's chosen number.

Here's a corrected version of your code:

```
from random import randint

number = int(input ("You have two dice to roll, what outcome do you want? "))
outcome = {2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0}
sim = 100

for simulations in range(sim):
    first_dice_roll = randint(1, 6)
    second_dice_roll = randint(1, 6)
    sum_dice = first_dice_roll + second_dice_roll
    outcome[sum_dice] += 1

if number in outcome.keys():
    print("Percentage for rolling a sum of %s is: %s" % (number, outcome[number] / sim * 100))
else:
    print("Invalid input. Please enter a number between 2 and 12.")
```

This version will correctly display the percentage of simulations that resulted in a sum equal to the user's input. It also handles invalid inputs by checking if the input number is within the keys of the outcome dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The odds of rolling a particular value with two dice can be calculated precisely.

If you want to simulate dice rolling in order to approximate the actual odds, then you should run much higher numbers of iterations/simulations. For example:

```
from random import randint
from collections import defaultdict

results = defaultdict(int)
simulations = 1_000_000

for _ in range(simulations):
    results[randint(1, 6) + randint(1, 6)] += 1

for k, v in sorted(results.items()):
    print(f'Percentage chances of rolling {k:>2} is {(v/simulations)*100:.2f}%')
```

**Output:**

```
Percentage chances of rolling  2 is 2.77%
Percentage chances of rolling  3 is 5.53%
Percentage chances of rolling  4 is 8.34%
Percentage chances of rolling  5 is 11.11%
Percentage chances of rolling  6 is 13.92%
Percentage chances of rolling  7 is 16.62%
Percentage chances of rolling  8 is 13.96%
Percentage chances of rolling  9 is 11.12%
Percentage chances of rolling 10 is 8.30%
Percentage chances of rolling 11 is 5.54%
Percentage chances of rolling 12 is 2.79%
```

Thus with 1 million simulations we see that the reported odds are very close to the actual known odds